# Why is this result true for complex numbers?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I read that for complex number if $\,0,z_1,z_2\,$ represent vertices of an equilateral triangle then

$$ z_1^2 +z_2^2 = z_1 z_2 $$

On plunging values $z_1=x+iy$  what value of $z_2$ should I use to proof this result. Is there a  more appropriate way to prove this

Comment: Any two points can be vertices of an equilateral triangle by choosing the third vertex appropriately...

Comment: The claim isn't true., as @EricWofsey points out.

Comment: http://www.mathematicalgemstones.com/gemstones/opal/equilateral-triangles-in-the-complex-plane/

Comment: "what value of z2 should I use to proof this result"  As any two points can be two of the three vertices of an equilater al triangle $z_2$ can be anything you like.  Say $w+iu$.  Then you must prove $(x+iy)^2 + (w+iu)^2 = (x+iy)(w+iu)$ for any two points, which you won't be able to do because its not true. On the other hand, if you want a result with three numbers and you an have $x+iy$ and $w+iu$ but then the third one will have to be $\alpha + i\beta$ so that $(w-x)^2 + (u-y)^2 = (\alpha -x)^2 + (\beta-y)^2 + (\alpha - u)^2  +(\beta - w)^2$.

Comment: @fleablood does the last expression results my proof on expanding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming your third vertex in the triangle is the origin.

Since the third vertex is the origin, $|z_1-0|=|z_2-0|$. Let this be $\def\E{\mathrm{e}}R\in\mathbb R$, and write $z_1=R\E^{i\theta} (\theta\in\mathbb R)$. Switching $z_1$ and $z_2$ if necessary, we see that $z_2=R\E^{i(\theta+\frac\pi3)}$. Now you should be able to simplify the equation to $\omega^2+1=\omega$ where $\omega=\E^{i\frac\pi3}$. This is true because $0=\omega^3+1=(\omega+1)(\omega^2-\omega+1)$ and $\omega\neq-1$.